# How to order items in array after frequency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

I'm writing an app where you can vote on certain players, these are later stored in the cloud and then they will be fetched for arrangement so you can see who got the most votes.

For now I fetch them

```
          NSMutableDictionary * dictofvotes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                for (NSString * name in people) {
                    int counts = [self repeatsOf:name people];
                    NSNumber * numero = [NSNumber numberWithInt:counts];
                    if ([dictofvotes objectForKey:name] == nil) {
                        [dictofvotes setObject:name forKey:numero];
                        NSLog(@"DICTO%@", dictofvotes);
                    }
                }
```

And this returns

```
DICTO
1 = "";
2 = 1069451903065548;
```

Which works, but later on I need to filter these to see who got the most votes. Then I would have to swipe through the dictionary and it seems as I am back on square 1 again. Any tips on how to do this or if there is an easier way from the beginning?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: What does the object 'People' look like, what properties does it contain?, what is the repeatsOf method doing exactly? Can you provide a little more code?

Comment: i think you can try to find a ordered dictionary implementation or you can have two identical data source, one in dictionary to quickly retrieve number of vote for someone and the other in an array so that it can be sorted to find out most voted people.

Comment: Thanks to @zp_x that did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me!

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictofvotes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    for (NSString * iden in lobbe) {
                        int counts = [self repeatsOf:iden inArray:lobbe];
                        NSNumber * numero = [NSNumber numberWithInt:counts];
                        if ([dictofvotes objectForKey:iden] == nil) {
                            if (numero > 0) {
                                [dictofvotes setObject:numero forKey:iden];
                            }
                            //[dictofvotes removeObjectForKey:@""];
                            NSLog(@"DICTO%@", dictofvotes);
                            //GO THROUGH VOTES TO SEE WHO HAS MOST STANNAR HÄR
                        }
                    }
                        NSMutableArray * numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
                        for(id key in dictofvotes) {
                            NSNumber * vote = [dictofvotes objectForKey:key];
                            [numbers addObject:vote];
                        }
                        NSLog(@"NUMBERS:%@", numbers);
                        NSNumber *max=[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"];
                        NSLog(@"MAX%@", max);
                        NSMutableArray * winners = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        for(id key in dictofvotes) {
                            NSNumber * num = [dictofvotes objectForKey:key];
                            NSLog(@"THENUM:%@", num);
                            if ([num doubleValue] == [max doubleValue]) {
                                NSString * string = key;
                                NSLog(@"THESTRING:%@, THE KEY:%@", string, key);
                                if (![string  isEqual: @""]) {
                                    [winners addObject:string];
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        NSLog(@"WINNERS:%@", winners);
```